# How do I prove this property about symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $A$ is symmetric and orthogonal. Prove that the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$.

I'm not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 3):

Orthogonal:

$$A^T A = Id$$

Symmetric:

$$A = A^T$$

Hence:

$$A^2=Id$$

If you have eigenvalue $\lambda$ whose eigenvector is $v$:

$$v=A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=\lambda^2 v$$

which gives you $\lambda = 1$ or $-1$

Answer (score 2):

If a matrix is symmetric, then $A = A^T$. As it is also orthogonal we have $AA^T = AA = I$.

Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$. So $Ax = \lambda x$. Then $$x = Ix = AAx = A\lambda x = \lambda Ax = \lambda^2 x.$$

Thus $\lambda^2 = 1$, so $\lambda = \pm 1$.